# map from string to multiple different strings and add to list with Java stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8 and Streams .
I got a PolicyDefinition object, that got to two method : getAlias,getName which both returns a string .
Is there an elegant way to create a list with all aliases and names of policy definitions using Stream (created from collection of PolicyDefinition) in one statement  ?

with two statements its not a problem :

```
List<String> policyNames = 
              policyDefinitions.stream()
                               .map(definition -> definition.getName())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> policyAlias = 
              policyDefinitions.stream()
                               .map(definition -> definition.getAlias())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But Is it possible in one ?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flatMap` it!

```
List<String> policyNames = policyDefinitions.stream()
    .flatMap(definition -> Stream.of(definition.getName(), definition.getAlias()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

As mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610164/map-from-string-to-multiple-different-strings-and-add-to-list-with-java-stream/49610193#comment86226854_49610193) - for tidyness, create a method in `Definition`

```
public Stream<String> allNames() {
    return Stream.of(getName(), getAlias())
}
```

Then

```
List<String> policyNames = policyDefinitions.stream()
    .flatMap(Definition::allNames)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

[OP comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610164/map-from-string-to-multiple-different-strings-and-add-to-list-with-java-stream/49610193?noredirect=1#comment86229355_49610193) "*I forgot to mention that `getAlias` might be `null`, what do you do than*[sic]"

In that case, use `Optional`:

```
public Stream<String> allNames() {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(getName()), Optional.ofNullable(getAlias()).stream())
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that getAlias might return null, what do you do than ?

Comment: Note, that optional only had a `stream` method as of JDK9, an alternative for JDK8 could be to create your own method that does such thing or filter the nulls out like `List<String> policyNames = policyDefinitions.stream()
    .flatMap(Definition::allNames).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Aominè Good point `Optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)` was a favourite of mine.

Comment: Or simply `Stream.of(getName(), getAlias()).filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create a Map with Alias as a Key and Name as a Value using groupingBuy operator